# Windows IIS load balancer works with MAC binded IP?

Tags: iis, load-balancer

Will windows IIS-ARR load balancer work with MAC binded IP or it is mandatory to have Virtual IP for the ARR load balancing Server.
I am referring to this ARR https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing .
I want to check this feasibility because Virtual IP is highly expensive than getting a MAC binded IP for the ARR server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TCP/IP over ethernet, all ip addresses need to be mac-bound in order to communicate.

”Virtual ip” vs ”mac-bound ip” is just a sales pitch from your ISP, all ip addresses are in reality mac-bound when using ethernet.

The so called ”mac-bound” ip is just a filter implemented by the ISP network, configured to require a pre-defined mac address to use a pre-defined ip address. This as a simple way for your ISP to ensure only one computer is using the connection. A measure which easily can be circumvented with a NAT-gateway, that is a proxy such as a firewall, in place between the ISP and the computers using the connection.

So to answer, IIS/ARR will function just as well as a ”virtual ip connected” server and as a ”mac-bound connected” server. Your server will in fact not be able to tell the difference. The ISP network department and ISP billing department will however see the difference, and you will too should you try to bind the ISP provided ip address to another network adapter having a different mac address to the one registered with your ISP.

However, connecting a server directly to the internet is not a safe practice. You should connect a firewall directly to the internet, letting it present its own mac address to your ISP and claiming the public IP address, then connecting your IIS server to the inside network of that firewall and configure it using a private address from your internal address space.

Using port forwarding in the firewall you can then make your IIS on the inside (using a private address) available from the internet on the outside (using a public address). And by doing so you will not only safeguard your server in the most basic fashion, but also circumvent the ISP filter sold to you as a ”mac-bound ip address” (the ISP will not even see your servers mac adress, only the firewall mac address). Using port forwarding in your firewall you would in fact be able to publish practically speaking any number of servers through the ”mac-bound” ip address, as your ISP will only see the firewall mac address as your servers mac addresses will be hidden behind it.

This is a recommended approach and an industry best practice (but not the only one). You should however take a look at the agreement with your ISP and see if they have  limited the number of servers you are allowed to publish through the firewall, a matter for your conscience and the legal department of your ISP.

More info on the relationship between mac and ip addresses [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-address-resolution-protocol-arp-works/) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/410626/why-couldnt-mac-addresses-be-used-instead-of-ipv46-for-networking)

Comment: Thanks for the info Erik.

Comment: Now I will have to test if my website hosted on IIS server will respond as expected even with a firewall.  I mean, when I request for https ://www.ABC.com I get my website home page. So will the client machine browser still get the home page if I put a firewall as well.

Comment: My actual challenge is, I have a payment gateway in my website, and it will work as expected only if the request comes to the website from the domain name (like www.ABC.com) or my public static IP . so if my server is behind the firewall, will it still receive the request from the website name www.ABC.com or  my public static IP. Please let me know. Anyway, I will post a new question for this.

Comment: Yes it will. You would in most cases tcp port forward port 443 in the firewall to port 443 on your server. The firewall will present a hardened surface blocking all other communication to the server and depending on brand do some sort of sanity check for incoming tcp/443.

Comment: That would be excellent. It makes my life easy. Thanks for the info. Let me do a trial run. And I will get back if any issue. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Please try to clarify my other query "Http Request after passing through firewall and loadbalancer". In Super User forum.